# xargs vertical alignment of output

Tags: grep, xargs

I want to extract certain values from files in many subdirectories. I have a working code that does this:

`for i in */; do grep "free  energy" "$i"filename | tail -1 | xargs -I{} echo "$i: {}" >> output.txt; done`

the `tail -1` command gives me the last output from each file (which I want) and the xargs construction prepends the folder name so I know which line belongs to which system. The output.txt looks like this:

`Cr/: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -18.87487583 eV
 Hf/: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -18.76845679 eV
 N/: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -15.90748159 eV
 Nb/: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -20.38801759 eV
 Ti/: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -14.92233353 eV
 TiN/: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -78.73147048 eV`

Where `Cr`, `Hf`, `N`, `TiN` and so on are the folder names. My problem is that the values on the right side are not aligned properly, because the folders have different character lengths. Changing the folder names is out of the question so I want the xargs command to always use a certain amount of spaces (like 10) - at least as a minimum - so the vertical alignment is proper. The result should look something like this:

`Cr/ : free  energy   TOTEN  =       -18.87487583 eV
 Hf/ : free  energy   TOTEN  =       -18.76845679 eV
 N/  : free  energy   TOTEN  =       -15.90748159 eV
 Nb/ : free  energy   TOTEN  =       -20.38801759 eV
 Ti/ : free  energy   TOTEN  =       -14.92233353 eV
 TiN/: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -78.73147048 eV`

or this

`Cr /: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -18.87487583 eV
 Hf /: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -18.76845679 eV
 N  /: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -15.90748159 eV
 Nb /: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -20.38801759 eV
 Ti /: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -14.92233353 eV
 TiN/: free  energy   TOTEN  =       -78.73147048 eV`

so that I can easily copy all the values at once with `Alt` + `Leftclick`.

Comment: Pipe through [column](https://linux.die.net/man/1/column) command.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is what you want

```
xargs -I{} printf "%-10s: %s\n" "$i" "{}"
```

Note that this will use /usr/bin/printf, not the shell's builtin printf.